# Google Contacts API not returning contacts with a directory profile

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-profiles-api, google-shared-contacts

I am trying to search through "my contacts" on my google account. The account belongs to a Google for Business domain. I have already managed to retrieve all contacts which works by querying to the following url:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full
```

or

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full
```

Now, when I search using the `q=searchString` or `myQuery.setFullTextQuery(searchString);` (in Java). I only get some of the results. In particular contacts that I have created and do not belong to the same domain as me.

I assume that this has to do with the fact that google has not stored a name entry for contacts tha have a directory profile. Thus it will only search within their email address (and if I'm lucky and the email address contains the name only then it will find it).

As a workaround I also get all the profiles (which does not seem to work with a full text search string) from the domain and then merge/parse them in order to get the results I need.

My question now is, is there a single call in order to retrieve ALL contacts (from my contacts) that contain a specific search string in either the NAME (first and last), EMAIL and perhaps field labels?

I do not see a point of using a full text search string when the contact entries that have a directory profile do not contain any name... (it is stored in the profile).

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should fill all fields manually(only primary email and photo shared between directory profile and your contact) in contact entry. So you can't find in one request all that you need